# iOS sqlite3 - what if file changes after sqlite3_open

Tags: ios, sqlite

Here's the scenario (I'm using iOS):

1. I've downloaded sqlite3 db from internet and saved it on disk.
2. I've opened db for reading with `sqlite3_open`
3. After some time I've updated db file from internet while app was running and never called `sqlite3_open` again

What db I'll have access to? Will it always be the fresh version from disk or it uses some kind of memory cached version?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you leave the database open while downloading a new copy? Close it, overwrite it, re-open it.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, I guess this is what I'll do.

Comment: It's what you must do if you want your app to work properly and use the updated database after downloading the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the database file while it is opened is not supported, and is likely to result in data corruption.

However, you can use an SQLite mechanism to replace the file: open the new file with the `sqlite3` command-line shell, then execute `.backup existingfile`. This will replace all data, while using proper locking and transactions.